# subprocess.Popen works outside but not inside ipyparallel?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, stanford-nlp, ipython-parallel

I'm trying to parallelize some code from [here](https://github.com/reedcoke/bigDataCamp2016/blob/master/sentiment.py) using `ipyparallel`. In short, I can make functions that work fine outside of `apply_sync()`, but I can't seem to get them to work inside it (I swear I had this working earlier, but I can't find a version of the code that isn't broken). A simple example:

```
def test3(fname = '7_1197_.txt'):
    import subprocess
    command = 'touch data/sentiment/' + fname + '.test'
    child = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        out = child.stdout.read(1)
        if out == '' and child.poll() != None:
            return 
test3() #this works, creates a file with the .test extention
results = view.map_sync(test3, speeches) #this doesn't work. No files created.
```

Here's a short version of the function I'm actually going to use. It works fine on its own. In `apply_sync()` it spins up `java` processes according to `htop`, but it doesn't seem to get anything back from those processes.

```
def test2(fname = '7_1197_.txt'):
    import subprocess

    settings = ' -mx5g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline'
    inputFile = ' -file data/sentiment/' + fname
    command = 'java ' + settings + inputFile
    child = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    results = []
    while True:
        out = child.stdout.read(1)
        if out == '' and child.poll() != None:
            return ''.join(results)
        if out != '':
            results.extend(out)
test2() #Works fine, produces output
results = view.map_sync(test2, speeches) #Doesn't work: the results are empty strings.
```

I tried a version where I return the command variable. The commands sent to `Popen` are fine, and they work when pasted manually in the command line. I thought maybe it was just an issue with piping, but changing the command to redirect the output to files with `' > '+fname+'.out'` doesn't work inside the `apply_sync()` call either (no output files are produced).

How should I be doing this so I get the `stdout` from the system calls back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two potential gotchas. One for the blocking, one for the missing files. For the missing files, you should make sure that your engines and your local session are in the same working directory, or make sure to use absolute paths. A quick way to synchronize paths locally and remotely:

```
client[:].apply_sync(os.chdir, os.getcwd())
```

That says: get the *local* cwd, then call `os.chdir` everywhere, so that we all share the same working directory. A quick shortcut for this if you are in an IPython session is:

```
%px cd {os.getcwd()}
```

As for the blocking, my first thought is: are you perhaps using Python 3 when running in parallel? If so, `child.stdout.read` returns *bytes* not *text*. In Python 2, `str is bytes`, so `out == ''` will work, but in Python 3, the condition `out == ''` will never be true because `b'' != u''`, and your function will never return.

Some more useful bits of info:

1. `stdout.read(N)` will read *up to* that number of bytes, and truncate if the output is complete. This is useful because `read(1)` will loop *many* times, even if the output is all waiting to be read.
2. `stdout.read()` will only return an empty bytestring if output is finished, so you only need to check that, not `child.poll()` before returning. (this is true as long as you haven't set NOWAIT on the FD, which is some advanced usage).
3. if you want to see partial output before the function returns, you can redisplay output on sys.stdout, and see the partial outputs in IPython without waiting for the final result.

So here are a couple of implementations of your function, with different goals.

The first one appears to accomplish your current goal using [Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), which is the simplest choice if you don't actually want to do anything with partial output and/or have nothing to do in the function wile you are waiting for output:

```
def simple(fname = '7_1197_.txt'):
    import subprocess
    command = 'echo "{0}" && touch -v data/sentiment/{0}.test'.format(fname)
    child = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # if we aren't doing anything with partial outputs,
    # child.communicate() does all of our waiting/capturing for us:
    out, err = child.communicate()
    return out
```

(it might be useful to include stderr capturing as well, with `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` or merge stderr into stdout with `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`).

Here's another example, collecting stderr into stdout, and reading in chunks:

```
def chunked(fname = '7_1197_.txt'):
    import subprocess
    command = 'echo "{0}" && touch data/sentiment/{0}.test'.format(fname)
    child = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                            )
    chunks = []
    while True:
        chunk = child.stdout.read(80) # read roughly one line at a time
        if chunk:
            chunks.append(chunk)
            continue
        else:
            # read will only return an empty bytestring when output is finished
            break
    return b''.join(chunks)
```

Note that we can use the `if not chunk` condition to determine when output is finished, rather than `if chunk == ''`, since empty bytestrings are Falsy. If we aren't doing something with the partial output, there's really no reason to use this instead of the simpler `.communicate()` version above.

Finally, here's a version you can use with IPython that, instead of capturing and returning the output, redisplays it, which we can use to display *partial* output in the client:

```
def chunked_redisplayed(fname = '7_1197_.txt'):
    import sys, subprocess
    command = 'for i in {{1..20}}; do echo "{0}"; sleep 0.25; done'.format(fname)
    child = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                            )
    while True:
        chunk = child.stdout.read(80) # read roughly one line at a time
        if chunk:
            sys.stdout.write(chunk.decode('utf8', 'replace'))
            continue
        else:
            # read will only return an empty bytestring when output is finished
            break
```

In the client, if you use `map_async` instead of `map_sync`, you can check on `result.stdout`, which is a list of the stdout-streams *so far*, so you can check on the progress:

```
amr = view.map_async(chunked_redisplayed, speeches)
amr.stdout # list of stdout text, updated in the background as output is produced
amr.wait_interactive() # waits and shows progress
amr.get() # waits for and returns the actual result
```

Comment: `child.communicate()` solves my issue, and the tip on synchronizing the directories is helpful too. I'm still confused as to why my ipcluster might be running in python 3, when my notebook / scripts calling it are in 2.7?

Comment: Likely PATH issues. You can check things like `sys.executable` and `os.environ['PATH']` in your various processes, and `which -a ipengine`, `which -a ipcluster` for possible discrepencies.